# Can jOOQ object mapping configured ensure all fields of POJO are set?

Tags: jooq

I'm mapping jOOQ results into POJOs.

I'd like to avoid having columns of the result not being mapped because of a typo/mismatch between field name and column name.

Is there a way to configure jOOQ to verify each field of the POJO is properly set ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done out of the box, but you can implement a custom `RecordMapperProvider` that implements the desired checks:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/pojos-with-recordmapper-provider